# When using subversion on macos and committing a file I receive the error sed: 1: "/Users/xxxxxxxxx/.sub ...": invalid command code e

Tags: macos, sed, svn

Apple M1 Max 13.0.1 (22A400) is the operating system I am running and I have never seen SED before I thought it was something to do with MAMP which I downloaded recently but after uninstalling it nothing happened

Have searched computer for all references to SED to no avail and can't seem to find a way to uninstall it

The commit and add codes I am running are:

```
touch newfile.cpp
svn add newfile.cpp
svn commit newfile.cpp -m "comment"
```

Comment: you need to install a gnu version of sed compatible with your installation of svn, that is one which supports the e code (macos default sed does not).  /usr/bin/sed is a basic part of your macos and is thereby not uninstallable.

Comment: @RichardBarber How will I find a version of sed compatible with my SVN installation?

Comment: probably the most recent (gnu) one for your platform will do.